# UFT How to pass different datatable for same action in different test cases

Tags: parameters, datatable, qtp

How to pass different datatable for same action in different test cases

I have three actions and two test cases which calls these action differently.

TC 1 calls action 1 and action 2

TC 2 calls action 1 and action 3 with different data for action 1

I know we could pass different parameters through action call properties but how can we do the same if we are using Data Table?

Thanks in advance for any input

---

All three Actions are saved as seperate script.

So this is our approach towards automating the application

1. We are trying to drive the automation from ALM and so mapping ALM parameters with UFT parameter
2. We are creating modular scripts for resuability which is defined by a functionality. If same functionality is being used in more than one test case we differentiate the step by the usage of a variable.
   Ex: A test case has a process to be run. Either we can use the template which was created earlier or create a new template to initiate the process. 
   Creation and Using template follow different steps initially but then routes through the same validation. we also have separate manual cases for these. Since only 2 steps are different, we have defined variable which differentiate these using the IF statement. So if variable has value 1, it creates template else run the existing template

Test Case 1 - Create New Template - Calling the modules with the Parameters defined during the call

RunAction "Action1 [Module_1]", oneIteration,  "Create New Template", "Parameter_1", "Parameter_2"
RunAction "Action1 [Module_2]", oneIteration,

Test Case 2 - Use Existing Template - Calling the modules with the Parameters defined during the call

RunAction "Action1 [Module_1]", oneIteration, "Use Existing Template", "Parameter_3", "Parameter_4"
RunAction "Action1 [Module_3]", oneIteration, "Parameter_5", "Parameter_6", "Parameter_7"

3. We are minimizing the usage of data table. However there are cases where data table cannot be avoided. Ex: Multiple Forms where user has to add more forms with same fields over and again. These are handled using data sets for each form, from data table. However there are different cases which uses this module and there has to be different data table for each case. How can I implement it? Currently since I am using the local data table from module I am unable to use it for different test case. Is there a way to use the local data table of the Test Case and then pass on the values to module?

Even if there is a way, there are limitations as "Add of form" mentioned in the above is just a part of a large functionality. So if we are to  iterate the module for the number of data sets in the data table, we would only need to include a part of the code in it

Not sure if I am explaining it properly but do let me know if you are unable to understand and I'll try to explain it better

Comment: Where are Action1, Action2 and Action3 defined? How are you calling them? Have you defined input parameters in the definitions of the 3 actions, or just refer to the local datatable?

Comment: I have tried to explain it in my initial post. Please let me know if you have trouble understanding it

Comment: Not totally sure Im understanding correctly BUT... If you need to call an external action, and it is that external action's datatable that you need to change for each test case, could you not have an additional XLS in the same format as default.xls in the external action's module, and, from the parent test case, copy this XLS over default.xls prior to calling the external action? I should add, it's been a while since I used QTP integration with QC/ALM so I don't know off hand where things like these XLS files would be stored, so....

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I'm talking about. So is there a way to copy the data table from test case on to the external action without using an external source. As like I can see suggestion to export to my computer and then import it back from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it sounds like you are trying to do something similar to what I have done... I should add this is not an ideal solution, but for the situation I found myself in, it works!

So I'm assuming `Module_1`, `Module_2`, and `Module_3` are technically QTP Tests that you never run. `Test_1`, and `Test_2` are also QTP Tests that you DO run(!) - which include `RunAction` calls as you mention above, plus any other bespoke code for that test. That's fine.

NOTE:  You do not need to have any data anywhere in the datatable of any of the "Modules".

Instead, define each of the Reusable Actions in each "Module" to take input Parameters. Then keep the data for those parameters in the datasheets for `Test_1`, `Test_2` etc - with each local (Action) datasheet with each Test having columns that correspond to the parameters for the reusable actions that are called within that Test Action.

Then call the Reusable Action:

```
RunAction "Action1 [Module1]", oneIteration, 
    dataTable.Value("someParam", dtLocalSheet), 
    dataTable.Value("someOtherParam", dtLocalSheet)
```

Note that it is important to understand - when using Call to Existing action, the DataTable (both dtGlobalSheet and dtLocalSheet) refer to that of the "parent" test, NOT that of the external action - even for the external code - effectively, the datasheet of the "Module" you call out to doesn't exist)

If you need to run `Test_1` or `Test_2` etc with different data, either:
  1. Simply just add rows to the datasheets within the test, or...
  2. Create a copy of `default.xls` (the one in the test, not "ReusableActions", and edit in Excel as appropriate - then before each run, copy the required data xls over default.xls, before running the test.

Better yet, if you are using QC / ALM for test management, do some googling on "Business Process Testing with QC/ALM" - and the "Business Component" for QC/ALM - I'm trying to get my current employers to go down that route. Described above is a "hack" to achieve what can be done far more cleanly using BPT....

Comment: Thanks Steve. I never thought of passing the parameter from data table of the Test to external action. However there is a limitation with this approach. 

One of my test has - Creating multiple payments for a user
This would essentially mean I would be providing with the user details once but creating multiple payment records. So only iterating the payment part based on the number

Comment: Sounds to me like the thing to do there would be split that test into two actions - one to provide the user details, the other to create the payments. Remove the 2nd from the test flow, then add a call using RunAction to it from the first, specifying something like "1-10" (for 10 payments) in the "iteration" parameter.....

Comment: BTW, if you're happy with the answer above, please "accept" it ;) thanks!

Comment: I was thinking the same but I thought I would have difficulty in iterating it. But I think something like below should work to iterate the payment module

RunAction "Action1 [Provide Detail]", oneIteration, "Parameter_1", "Parameter_2" 
For i = 1 to n
datatable.setcurrentrow(i)
RunAction "Action1 [Create Payment]", oneIteration, dataTable.Value("someParam", dtLocalSheet), 
 dataTable.Value("someOtherParam", dtLocalSheet)
Next

Comment: We dont have BPT licenses purchased for ALM so wouldnt be able to check on that. However it will get me close to what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You should find you can do `RunAction "Action1 [Create Payment]", 1-n, dataTable.Value("someParam", dtLocalSheet), dataTable.Value("someOtherParam", dtLocalSheet)` - without the need for the for loop....